# Writing web service to find shortest path

Tags: java, android, web-service

I need to create a web service  wich will communicate with my android application .in my android app the client choose two point start and arrival this two point will be send to my web service to find the bus that has the shortest path between them.
i have a problem analytically and  programmatically  i  find a dijkstra algorithme in this link http://www.vogella.com/code/de.vogella.algorithms.dijkstra/codestartpage.html
and i find this also http://www.codeweblog.com/dijkstra-shortest-path-algorithm-to-optimize-combat/

Can you help me with which one i choose  and  how can i establish a relationship between this algorithme and my data base may be i need to  send or retrieve the bulk of data in arraylist?

What are the classes needed?

What is the query that i need and in which classe do I write them?

I use eclipse ide.